# How do I group my package imports into a single custom package?

Tags: perl, package

Normally when I am writing the perl program . I used to include following package .

```
use strict ; 
use warnings ; 
use Data::Dumper ;
```

Now , I want like this, I will not include all this package for every program . for that
I will have these all package in my own package. like following.

**my_packages.pm**

```
package my_packages  ; 
{
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Data::Dumper;
}
1;
```

So, that if I add my_packages.pm in perl program , it needs have all above packages .

Actually I have done this experimentation . But I am not able get this things . 
which means when I am using my_packages . I am not able get the functionality of "use strict, use warnings , use Data::Dumper ".

Someone  help me out of this problem.....

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678263/how-can-i-extend-mooses-automatic-pragma-exports, which discusses the same thing but regarding Moose modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [`ToolSet`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ToolSet/), which does all the dirty import work for you.

Usage example from pod:

**Creating a ToolSet:**

```
# My/Tools.pm
package My::Tools;

use base 'ToolSet'; 

ToolSet->use_pragma( 'strict' );
ToolSet->use_pragma( 'warnings' );
ToolSet->use_pragma( qw/feature say switch/ ); # perl 5.10

# define exports from other modules
ToolSet->export(
 'Carp'          => undef,       # get the defaults
 'Scalar::Util'  => 'refaddr',   # or a specific list
);

# define exports from this module
our @EXPORT = qw( shout );
sub shout { print uc shift };

1; # modules must return true
```

**Using a ToolSet:**

```
use My::Tools;

# strict is on
# warnings are on
# Carp and refaddr are imported

carp "We can carp!";
print refaddr [];
shout "We can shout, too!";
```

/I3az/

Answer (score 3):

This is harder than you expect.

- For pragmas like `strict` and `warnings` you can pass them through.
- For modules that don't export functions such as object oriented ones, it will work.
- However for modules that export by default, like Data::Dumper (it gives you the `Dumper()` function in the package of the caller), it is trickier.

You can make it work by telling `Exporter` that there is an extra layer of magic:

So you could do:

```
package my_packages;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; 
use IO::Socket;


$Exporter::ExportLevel = 1; # Tell Exporter to export to the caller

sub import {

    # Enable this in the callers package

    strict->import;       # pragma in caller
    warnings->import;     # pragma in caller
    Data::Dumper->import; # Adds Dumper() to caller

    # No need for IO::Socket since it's OO.

    return 1;
}

1;
```

For three modules, this hardly seems to be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
package Foo;

use warnings;

sub import {
    warnings->import;
}

1;
```

And now:

```
$ perl <<CUT
> use Foo;
> \$a = 5; # backslash just to keep the $ from being eaten by shell
> CUT
Name "main::a" used only once: possible typo at - line 2.
```

Taken from [Modern::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Modern::Perl).